# Is the object cached?

Tags: cache, oop

I have a function to instantiate a class to provide var access to other functions.

```
function my_data(){
global $post,$the_data;
$postid = get_the_ID();
$the_data = new MY_Class ( $postid );
return $the_data;
}
```

This function will be called by every post, and each post will call it many times whenever need a var from MY_Class.
The data is saved in WordPress postmeta and retrived in My_Class. 
Does WP automatically cache the object, or should I find a way to cache it? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the WordPress API to retrieve the metadata, then it should be cached for you.

If you do other complex stuff, there is the [Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) for caching data yourself, which will take advantage of whatever object cache you use with WordPress.

EDIT - I should clarify, it'll be loaded for each request unless you use some sort of caching plugin, though it should load only once for each request.

Comment: Thanks, Milo! I use get_post_custom to retrive the data from postmeta table. So, that means the objects are cached. That's great!